# Computed twig Automatically update the computed value using Ajax

Tags: webforms

Whe I use computed twig with "Automatically update the computed value using Ajax" checket, it create "update" button next to my computed twig field. How I make the field update really automaticlally without this update button.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figgured out. It was because the theme template rewrite the form input element and this broke automatic comuting on forms.